# Can you use the gatsby-source-mongodb to POST data?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I have gatsby-source-mongodb set up on my gatsby react web app. Querying data from the db is fine as I can use graphql to bring in the data. I'm wondering if I can also use graphql to post using the their standard post request procedure.

Naturally what I'd do is use fetch or axios to post the data to mongodb but I don't know if that would be redundant in this scenario.  [image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not redundant as far as I understand your use-case. Let's say you have a user input (a form for example) and you want to store that data in your MongoDB, you will be forced to use an axios or `fetch` request (`POST`) request to send the data to the server.

On the other side of your application, you may want to fetch the data again to display it to the user, in that scenario, you will need to use an axios or `fetch` request (`GET`). If you to get the data in the build time `gatsby-source-mongodb` will fetch for it.

> Can you use the `gatsby-source-mongodb` to POST data?

Well, answering the question: no. `gatsby-source-mongodb` will only be fired in the build time, as soon as you run `gatsby build` command and it has only 1 direction. It doesn't make sense to send data at that specific point because you don't have any data to send back. But of course, in any React lifecycle, you can send the desired data back to the server.